# Как передать коллекцию объектов в DropDownList в asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

У меня есть две модели со связью многие-ко-многим:

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
    public int YearOfPublishing { get; set; }
    public string PublicHouseName { get; set; } ///
    public int PublicHouseId { get; set; } ///
    public LibraryType Type { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PublicHouse> PublicHouses { get; set; }

    public Book()
    {
        PublicHouses = new List<PublicHouse>();
    }
}


public class PublicHouse
{
    [Key]
    public int PublicHouseId { get; set; }

    public string PublicHouseName { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }

    public PublicHouse()
    {
        Books = new List<Book>();
    }
}
```

и две view model для этих сущностей

```
public class BookViewModel
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is Required")]
    [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Must be under 15 characters")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string AuthorName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is Required")]
    [Range(1, 2019, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 1 and 2019")]
    public int YearOfPublishing { get; set; }

    public string PublicHouseName { get; set; } //

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is Required")] //
    [Range(1, 10, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 1 and 10")] //
    public int PublicHouseId { get; set; } //

}

public class PublicHouseViewModel
{
    public int PublicHouseId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is Required")]
    [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Must be under 15 characters")]
    public string PublicHouseName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is Required")]
    [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Must be under 15 characters")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Есть метод `Create` для добавления новой книги в бд:

```
public void Create(BookViewModel bookViewModel)
{
    var book = Mapper.Map<BookViewModel, Book>(bookViewModel);
    book.Type = LibraryType.Books;
    IEnumerable<PublicHouse> publicHouses = _publicHouseRepository.GetAll(); //
    book.PublicHouseName = publicHouses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PublicHouseId == book.PublicHouseId)?.PublicHouseName;//

    _bookRepository.Create(book);
}
```

В этом методе происходит маппинг модели и вью модели, а так же получение всех объектов типа `PublicHouse`. свойству `book.PublicHouseName` присваивается имя сва-ва объекта `PublicHouse` в соответствии с `Id`.

Как мне получить список всех имен объектов `PublicHouse`, чтобы при создании новой книги выводить их в `DropDownList` в представлении?

Comment: получение всех объектов: IEnumerable<PublicHouse> publicHouses = _publicHouseRepository.GetAll();

Comment: Список "всех имён всех объектов PublicHouse" - это publicHouses.Where(x => x.PublicHouseId == book.PublicHouseId).Select(x => new SelectListItem{Id = x.Id, Name = x.PublicHouseName}) и есть же хелперы для получения SelectList. У вас MVC какой версии?

Comment: version="5.2.3"